# X11 screen switching to fullscreen with no taskbar (fltk2.0)

Tags: window, fullscreen, xlib

I am using fltk2.0 (which is now deprecated) to manage my windows.  My problem is on Linux when I want to create a fullscreen window, the window gets created but the KDE taskbar appears on top.  The relevant piece of Xlib code is the following:

```
#if USE_X11
    // This will make some window managers obey the border being turned on/off.
    // Most other modern window managers will allow the border to be placed
    // off-screen:
    // Unfortunatly stoopid MetaCity raises the window. Sigh
    CreatedWindow::find(window)->sendxjunk();

# if 1
    // Supposedly this tells the new X window managers to put this atop 
    // the taskbar. My tests have shown absolutly zero effect, so this is
    // either wrong or the window managers are ignoreing it. Newer X
    // window managers seem to work without this, they probably recognize
    // attempts to make the window the size of the screen

    // this method does in fact work, and is used below in my maximize()
    // so it should probably work here as well
    // possible problem is that sometimes one have to process/flush events
    // i.e. by using fltk::wait(1) to have this working
    // Perhaps below code can be done correctly(?) again - look at maximize()
    // (or perhaps Im totally wrong, Im new to Xlib  ;)  --Rafal

    static Atom _NET_WM_STATE;
    static Atom _NET_WM_STATE_REMOVE;
    static Atom _NET_WM_STATE_ADD;
    static Atom _NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN;
    if (!_NET_WM_STATE) {
# define MAX_ATOMS 30
      Atom* atom_ptr[MAX_ATOMS];
      const char* names[MAX_ATOMS];
      int i = 0;
# define atom(a,b) atom_ptr[i] = &a; names[i] = b; i++
      atom(_NET_WM_STATE        , "_NET_WM_STATE");
      atom(_NET_WM_STATE_REMOVE , "_NET_WM_STATE_REMOVE");
      atom(_NET_WM_STATE_ADD    , "_NET_WM_STATE_ADD");
      atom(_NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN, "_NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN");
# undef atom
      Atom atoms[MAX_ATOMS];
      XInternAtoms(xdisplay, (char**)names, i, 0, atoms);
      for (; i--;) *atom_ptr[i] = atoms[i];
    }


    XEvent e;
    memset( &e, 0, sizeof(e) );
    e.type = ClientMessage;
    e.xclient.window = xid(window);
    e.xclient.message_type = _NET_WM_STATE;
    e.xclient.format = 32;
    e.xclient.data.l[0] = fullscreen ? _NET_WM_STATE_ADD : _NET_WM_STATE_REMOVE;
    e.xclient.data.l[1] = _NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN;
    e.xclient.data.l[2] = 0;
    e.xclient.data.l[3] = 0;
    e.xclient.data.l[4] = 0;
    XSendEvent(xdisplay, RootWindow(xdisplay, xscreen), 0,
               SubstructureNotifyMask|SubstructureRedirectMask, &e);
# endif
# endif
```

The window gets to be fullscreen like I'd like if I go ALT+F3->More actions->Fullscreen (this covers the taskbar).  Any help in seeing what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried another Desktop Environment?

Comment: I tried it with XCF and Xubuntu Desktop and the same happens

Comment: Well I'm not sure what missing but here a small snippet that worked for me in this answer  http://askubuntu.com/a/576739/26246 also tested on Xubuntu 16.04. Here how it should appear https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zw_ECdeyc-s

Answer (score 0):

I have since switched my application to fltk1.4, which contains a window->fullscreen() function that works just great.  Thank you all for sharing your answers.